# Light sensor gauge

Tags: android, view, sensors, gauge

**INTRODUCTION**

For my job, I need to use a Light sensor for certain aplication. As I'm learning android, I decided to create a simple app that reads light sensor's values an shows it.

**CONCERN**

I know how to read light sensor's values and I'm actualy doing it. What I need is to create a gauge that represents these values. Something like this:

[image]

Being the lower limit 0, and higher limit something like 30000lx (my mobile can read up to 60000lx but I think that 30000lx is enough).

To do this, I started a tutorial from [here](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/). But I'm not able to adapt the temperature values to light values and redesing the scale, as as you can see on the picture, there are numbers floating, I don't get to put values, the hand doesn't appear, etc.

[image]

So, I would appreciate a lot If someone could help me adapting the code from this tutorial, providing me any example or link, or anything that could help me to finish the app.

Comment: Learning android you should perhaps not start with programming custom views... Why not simply use a ProgressBar to show your value? It's not radial but just linear but would be much easier.

Comment: Well, the thing is that I know basic concepts and what I want now is start with a bit more dificult things as custom views, that's why I see this as an oportunity to learn well how do custom views work

Comment: Okay that's a valid point :-) Does the example code run correctly if you do not change it? Then you should just try step by step to adapt it, so you find out when it breaks what made it break.

Comment: @Ridcully well, I've found that in the example, the needle doesn't show heither. So there is the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've decided to base in this one [LINK](https://github.com/ntoskrnl/SpeedometerView)